# how can i record and play my voice in real time using c/c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, real-time, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am recording my voice using mic. I have used waveIn() and waveOut() function for this purpose. When I start recording using waveInStart() function, it first completely record my voice for specified time and store it in a ()buffer and later play back my voice from that buffer. During recording and during playing , it does nothing. I want to record and play at the same time .
for that purpose I want to access the buffer during recording . How is this possible ? Or any other suggestion will be helpful.

```
Here is the code :


#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

 short int waveIn[8000 * 3];

void PlayRecord();
void writedataTofile(LPSTR lpData,DWORD dwBufferLength);

void StartRecord()
{
const int NUMPTS = 8000 * 3;   // 3 seconds
int sampleRate = 8000;  
// 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
                         // for 8-bit capture, you'd use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit     types

 HWAVEIN      hWaveIn;
 MMRESULT result;

 WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
 pFormat.wFormatTag=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // simple, uncompressed format
 pFormat.nChannels=1;                    //  1=mono, 2=stereo
 pFormat.nSamplesPerSec=sampleRate;      // 8.0 kHz, 11.025 kHz, 22.05 kHz, and 44.1 kHz
 pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec=sampleRate*2;   // =  nSamplesPerSec × nBlockAlign
 pFormat.nBlockAlign=2;                  // = (nChannels × wBitsPerSample) / 8
 pFormat.wBitsPerSample=16;              //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
 pFormat.cbSize=0;

 // Specify recording parameters

 result = waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER,&pFormat,
        0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

  WAVEHDR      WaveInHdr;
 // Set up and prepare header for input
  WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
  WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS*2;
  WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded=0;
  WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
  WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
  WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;
  waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

 // Insert a wave input buffer
  result = waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));


 // Commence sampling input
  result = waveInStart(hWaveIn);


 cout << "recording..." << endl;

  Sleep(3 * 1000);
 // Wait until finished recording

 waveInClose(hWaveIn);
PlayRecord();
}

void PlayRecord()
{
const int NUMPTS = 8000 * 3;   // 3 seconds
int sampleRate = 8000;  
// 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
                            // for 8-bit capture, you'd    use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit types

HWAVEIN  hWaveIn;

WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
pFormat.wFormatTag=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // simple, uncompressed format
pFormat.nChannels=1;                    //  1=mono, 2=stereo
pFormat.nSamplesPerSec=sampleRate;      // 44100
pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec=sampleRate*2;   // = nSamplesPerSec * n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
pFormat.nBlockAlign=2;                  // = n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
pFormat.wBitsPerSample=16;              //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
pFormat.cbSize=0;

// Specify recording parameters

waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER,&pFormat, 0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

WAVEHDR      WaveInHdr;
// Set up and prepare header for input
WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS*2;
WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded=0;
WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;
waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
cout << "playing..." << endl;
waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat, 0, 0, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WaveInHdr)); // Playing the data
Sleep(3 * 1000); //Sleep for as long as there was recorded


waveInClose(hWaveIn);
waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
}
int main()
{
 StartRecord();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if you allocate the buffer, you can assign the in and output to the same buffer, and running a thread to do the playback and a thread to do the recording. However, I expect you will need more than that by a fair amount.

The problem is that the buffer content will be loaded from memory into the hardware by some mechanism, and this "pre-reads" the data for playback in small blocks, as well as "buffering" the record side. Both the driver and the hardware will have some of this "caching" mechanism. This means that the playback will have read the data before it has been stored in memory from the recording, which of course won't work correctly.

The way most audio-processing systems work is by delaying the output a little bit, so you input a little bit, process it, output it. This, of course, causes a small delay, which can be rather annoying.

Comment: delay is not a problem for me but I can't miss any data
During playing the audio , whatever I speak is not recorded and I miss that  data :(

Answer (score 0):

Before you call waveInStart you can prepare and add several buffers to the audio driver. The driver will queue them and sequence from buffer to buffer without losing any data. You will have to use the fdwOpen flag in waveInOpen so you get a notification every time a buffer has been filled.

waveOut has the same queueing ability: You can output a buffer while it is playing the previous buffer and it will sequence smoothly between buffers.

So instead of one big 3 second buffer you might use ten 0.3 second buffers and write code to juggle these buffers from record to play as they get filled. The result will be audio without pauses, but with a 0.3 second delay.